# Excel Filter data display | Unable to view the blank cell data when filter is selected. Refer screenshot and description to understand more

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-filter

I am using an excel filter to display the data. I have a requirement where I am supposed to display data based on selected value, but since my excel data is a blank value, it does not display those rows

[image: My excel data]

I want that If I select "Loan" activity, I should be able to see rows 2, 3 4 i.e. (Loan form fill, Loan processing, and Loan disbursement. Note, I do not want to duplicate the value on the activity column hence I haven't written any values in B3 and B4.

Expected: If I select a loan, I am expecting the below to get displayed

[image: Expected rows to be displayed when Loan filter is selected]

Answer (score 1):

Good Day,

If select Loan on the activity column filter it will only show you rows that have Loan in the related cell in column B.

I believe your best bet is to populate Loan in or investment..in all cells in column B, or since it appears that the word loan appears in all related cells in  column C filter for loan in column C.

[image]

[image]

Hopefully, this helps

Comment: As an alternative to filling in the values in column `B`, OP can add a helper column to pull the last non-blank value from column `B` into another column. For instance, they can use this formula in `D2`: `=LOOKUP(2,1/(B$2:B2<>""),B$2:B2)` and then copy / paste it down to fill as many rows as needed.